# Robot Simulation in Java

Tags: java, simulation, robotics

I am doing a project concerning robot simulation and i need help. I have to simulate the activities of a robot in a warehouse. I am using mindstorm robots and lego's for the warehouse. The point here is i have to simulate all the activities of the robot on a Java GUI. That is whenever the robot is moving, users have to see it on the GUI a moving object which represents the robot.

When the roads/rails/crossings of the warehouse changes it must also be changed on the screen. The whole project is i have to simulate whatever the robot is doing in the warehouse in real-time. Everything must happen in real-time

I am asking which libraries in Java i can use to do this simulations in real-time and if someone can also point me to any site for good information. Am asking for libraries in Java that i can use to visualize the simulation in real-time.

Comment: Note that "real-time" has a special meaning in software. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_computing

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps the easiest (if not best) place to start is the "Java2D" API: http://java.sun.com/products/java-media/2D/index.jsp

Answer (score 3):

MASON http://cs.gmu.edu/~eclab/projects/mason/ is a nice Java multi-agent 2D simulator that can be used for many robotics problems.

Answer (score 1):

In such scenarios the interfacing is done using [ARIA](http://robots.mobilerobots.com/wiki/ARIA), all popular robots as [Pioneer P3-DX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autonomous_research_robot) and [Khepera](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khepera_mobile_robot) can be controlled by ARIA. I guess that [LABVIEW](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Labview) can also be used, however I am not sure. All these softwares are more or less C++/Java like !

Even [Lego Mindstorms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lego_Mindstorms) can probably be married to a real-time on screen GUI (read about it, never did it)